# How to inherit from a scipy.sparse matrix properly?

Tags: python, oop, scipy

I try to add my own methods and properties to a sparse matrix by multiple inheritance. But I found that the arithmetic operators are not closed in the new class.

```
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix
import numpy as np

class Info(object):
    def __init__(self, *arg, **args):
        self.hello = "hello"
    def say_hello(self):
        print("hello")

class A(coo_matrix, Info):
    def __init__(self, *arg, **args):
        super(type(self), self).__init__(*arg, **args)

a = A(np.random.randint(2, size=(3,3)))
print("type of a: ",type(a))
a.say_hello()
b = 2*a
print("type of b: ",type(b))
```

Comment: This could be tricky.  The different sparse `formats` are implemented as different classes.  Each class has an `__init__`, but also ways of converting to/from other formats.  For example most calculations are done with the `csr` (or `csc`) format.  For a start I"d suggest studying one of the formats that is intended primarily as an input method to see how it interacts with the others, e.g. `dia_matrix`, `dok_matrix`, `bsr_matrix` or `lil_matrix`.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the documentation of [scipy.sparse.coo_matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html), it does not directly support arithmetic operations. Apparently, if you still try do arithmetics, it automatically gets converted to a `csr_matrix`. This is why your `b` is not of type `__main__.A` anymore. However, if you instead inherit form, for instance, `csr_matrix` directly by doing

```
class A(csr_matrix, Info):
    ...
```

this has the proper methods for arithmetics and therefore works without being converted to another format.

Comment: But the transpose of a `csr` matrix is a `csc` matrix.  And many math operations on a `csr` produce a dense array or matrix.

Comment: So what's your point? Not using `csr` matrices? And why is it relevant what the transpose is? If `csc` is a better option for the arithmetics your doing of course you can also inherit from that.